# Android. Корректное завершение видеозвонка по webRtc. При повторном звонке MediaStream не отображается внутри surfaceViewRenderer

Tags: android, webrtc

Делаю видеозвонки по webRtc с помощью этой либы:

```
implementation 'com.mesibo.api:webrtc:1.0.5'
```

Проблема: после завершения звонка между абонентами, если перезванивать снова, то не отображается видео оппонента в surfaceViewRenderer-e (и звука оппонента нет тоже) (колбэк `onAddStream` внутри `PeerConnection.Observer` звонящего - при принятии звонка оппонентом - отрабатывает).

1. Направьте на путь истинный - почему это может происходить?
2. Какие обязательные действия нужно выполнить у обоих собеседников при завершении разговора, помимо `peerConnection.close()`, т.е. что еще нужно *очистить/закрыть/диспоузнуть*, чтобы все было снова готово для нового видеозвонка?